# Custom v/s Customized v/s Personal

Tags: word-usage

We have a small start up and need a tag line for it. We deal in custom products that we make according to their requirements. We have come up with 'Customized Technology Solutions'. But, now we have a question, is 'Custom Technology Solutions' the correct usage or is it customized itself. Also, is it wrong to use 'Personalized Technology Solutions'?

Does customized make it seem that we modify products not actually make new ones?

Answer (score 2):

The word you're looking for might be *bespoke,* which means made to custom requirements.  "Tailor-made" (or just "tailored") is a common allegory with the same meaning.

"Custom" as an adjective is fine too.  *Customized* probably does suggest "modified from something else".  "Personalized" would be an odd choice of words if your customers are businesses rather than individuals; to me it also connotes something shallower than "customized", along the lines of just painting a name on something rather than changing its essential nature.

Comment: Can you please help me with the tag line, Bespoke technology solutions just doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Personally I like "tailored"-- just don't call it Tailored IT Solutions, because of the acronym...

Comment: Although it's gained some traction in the past several years, *bespoke* is still essentially unknown in the US.

Answer (score 2):

I feel you should stick with "custom."  Personalized is not an option because the dictionary gives a meaning as "engraving, or monogrammed with one's initials," which is not what you are doing.

Custom means "made to order" and to me does not have the feeling of taking something that already exists and modifying it.  Customized could be seen in that way, although the dictionary does not support that "could be seen."

Bespoke and tailored are used for clothing so are not at all appropriate.

Comment: "Bespoke" is not specific to clothing; it's the past participle of "bespeak", which simply means to order (decree) something.  "Tailored" does literally refer to clothing but, in an allegorical sense, it is very widely used in other contexts (software, loans, spa breaks...).

Comment: @bobtato do you know what the word "allegory" means?

Comment: @bobtato also, no one would say "I have a bespoken paint job on my car," or "My company provides bespoken training programs."  No one.

Comment: True, since "bespoken" isn't a word, but if you google either "bespoke auto paint job" or "bespoke training", you can see many examples of each.